# Figuring out WhatsApp's receipt info storage format

Tags: file-format

I am trying to figure out and document the structure of WhatsApp's database (iOS version). Most data is easily readable, but the table `ZWAMESSAGEINFO` has a `BLOB`-column `ZRECEIPTINFO`. I am guessing this would contain information about when a message has been received/read, but can't decode the binary format. Attatched are two examples. I would suspect the time to be saved in Mac absolute time, but can't find anything that looks like a date in the data.

`ZRECEIPTINFO` of a message that has been read on 11th April 2022, 12:17 CEST (GMT+2) and was delivered on 11th April 2022, 11:07 CEST (GMT+2):

```
121b0a088153000000360057200028952152040800100052040804100018bcdfcf92062002
```

`ZRECEIPTINFO` of a message that has been read on 13th April 2022, 19:18 CEST (GMT+2) and was delivered 13th April 2022, 19:17 CEST (GMT+2):

```
12140a08814b4d00395805442000282252040800100018bd8bdc92062002
```

Any insight or idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feels more like a protobuf format - Use an [online decoder](https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app/) to play around.

```
$ echo 121b0a088153000000360057200028952152040800100052040804100018bcdfcf92062002 | xxd -r -p | protoc --decode_raw
2 {
  1: "\201S\000\000\0006\000W"
  4: 0
  5: 4245
  10 {
    1: 0
    2: 0
  }
  10 {
    1: 4
    2: 0
  }
}
3: 1649668028
4: 2
```

Field 3 is 1649668028 which fits neatly with the times you mentioned. Here it is formatted in UTC

```
$ echo 121b0a088153000000360057200028952152040800100052040804100018bcdfcf92062002 | xxd -r -p | protoc --decode_raw | grep "^3:" | awk '{print strftime("%c", $2, 1)}'
Mon Apr 11 09:07:08 2022
$ echo 12140a08814b4d00395805442000282252040800100018bd8bdc92062002 | xxd -r -p | protoc --decode_raw | grep "^3:" | awk '{print strftime("%c", $2, 1)}'
Wed Apr 13 17:17:49 2022
```

I need more details such as other columns - maybe phone number? to be sure.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn‘t aware of protobuf. I tried this on a few other rows and it does seem to be the answer. I suspect field 3 to be the timestamp of when the message was sent and fields 4 and 5 of field 2 to be an offset from that time to when the message was received/read. Probably field 1 of field 2 is an ID of the recipient (useful for group messages with many recipients) though I haven‘t figured out the format yet. Not sure why it wants that to be a string though as it obviously has many non-ascii-characters.

Comment: @GeF I don't have access to any dump or an iOS device. The more messages I get I'd be able to correlate and guess. Considering the messages are private, do you access to some public dataset?

Comment: Sadly I don‘t have access to a public dataset, but I figured out how to read field 2->1: look at the hex representation of the field and read from the third character and you will get the phone number. Thanks for you help!